# Show DIV dynamically when clicking on Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have been supplied with this code that I can't seem to get working, I've looked around previous questions but can't find anything exactly like it. Maybe it's just totally wrong and should just start again?

What I want to do is show a div when a radio button is selected. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[name="item_meta[478]"]').change(function(){
var val1 = $("input[name='item_meta[478]']:checked").val();
if (val1== "España") {
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
}
if (val1== "Intracomunitario") {
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

<form>
Show form?
<input type="radio" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'478')" checked="checked" value="España" id="field_478-0" name="item_meta[478]">España
<input id="field_478-1" type="radio" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'478')" value="Intracomunitario" name="item_meta[478]">Intracomunitario
</form>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Custom form España
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Custom form Intracomunitario
</div>
```

Thanks a lot !

A programmer told me I could do what I want to do with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[name="item_meta[988]"], input[name="item_meta[989]"]').change(function(){
var val1 = $("input[name='item_meta[988]']:checked").val();
var val2 = $("input[name='item_meta[989]']:checked").val(); 
if (val1 !=undefined && val2 != undefined)
{$("#field_keytotal").val(val1+' '+val2);}
});
});
</script>
```

And:

```
<form>
Show form? 
<input type="radio" id="showform" value="yes" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/>Yes
<input type="radio" id="showform" value="no" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/>No
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showhideForm(showform) {
    if (showform == "yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    } 
    if (showform == "no") {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
[formidable id=18]
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
You are not qualified to see this form.
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/cvn6n/72](http://jsfiddle.net/cvn6n/72)

Comment: Is Jquery being loaded?

Comment: this code is not complete and has a missing `}` just before the ending `</script>` tag - could you provide us with the declaration of the `frmCheckDependent` function and possibkly answer the question @General_Twyckenham posed?

Comment: frmCheckDependent shouldn't shouldn't have anything to do with it. I didn't realize I had copied without the }. I have included the original code that was used...

Comment: add a jsbin or fiddle or something so we can see the code fail ourselves please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cvn6n/72/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing bracket. Add one before the `</script>`

Comment: K. Try making a JSFiddle as @b_dubb said so we can see it.